# How to find all numerical roots in exponential equation?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I have this function:

```
d = 7.61;
beta = 0.0193;
lnot = 74.1;
morse[x_] := d*(1 - Exp[-beta*(x - lnot)])^2;
```

and I can see there are 2 roots because when I do

```
CountRoots[morse[x], x]
2
```

I am looking for a function that as an output it would give me the two roots like this:

```
{{x -> root1}, {x -> root2}}
```

Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just use Solve, i.e., `Solve[morse[x]==0, x]` or `Solve[morse[x]==0, x, Reals]`.

Comment: There's only one root (at `lnot`) but it's a double-root, so it gets counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you rationalize the equation and use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), it is easier to see that the roots are identical.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
d = 7.61 // Rationalize;
beta = 0.0193 // Rationalize;
lnot = 74.1 // Rationalize;
morse[x_] := d*(1 - Exp[-beta*(x - lnot)])^2;

sol = Solve[{morse[x] == 0, 72 < x < 76}, x]

(* {{x -> 741/10}, {x -> 741/10}} *)

morse[x] /. sol

(* {0, 0} *)

Clear[lnot];

sol = Solve[morse[x] == 0, x, Reals]

(* {{x -> lnot}} *)
```